# Sorting of top users by tag

Tags: feature-request, tags, reputation, top-users

Why does a user with more posts, but with the same reputation (on a tag) show up on top? [E.g.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/discussion/topusers):

> [image: rep - post]

The first number shows reputation and the second shows the number of posts. If a user creates fewer posts and earns the same reputation like another user with more posts, such a user should be considered more effective and positioned on top of users with same rep. Isn't that so?

Comment: Hmm, probably the idea is that writing more answers takes more effort anyway. That's probably the most accurate thing that can be said about this, since it's possible that a user gains massive rep from few posts that make it to HNQ.

Comment: I wonder if there's a time element involved there too - or simply "bigger numbers float to the top" where there's a tie. Gotta organise things somehow.

Comment: I really doubt the developers put much, or any, thought into this. (When I sort lists, I usually don't pay much attention to the UX involved. If the company wants, they'll hire UX experts that will skim through stuff and ask the developers to change things.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, and no.

### Background:

One of the problems that has haunted Stack Exchange sites for as long as I can remember, is that some questions will go *unanswered*, earning OP's the [tumbleweed badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/38/tumbleweed).

[Taken from StackOverflow (SO):](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/63/tumbleweed)

[image: Tumbleweed badge screenshot]

<sup>****November 6th, 2017@11:51PM** (UTC-09:00) Alaska*</sup>

## Yes:

You are right in the sense that [Shadow Wizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/152859/shadow-wizard) is much more *concise* and *helpful* with each of his answers (*in accords to the data*).

## No:

However, since he responds less abundantly, **it worsens the SE issue of leaving questions *unanswered***

[The prime example (taken from SO):](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered)

[image]

<sup>****November 6th, 2017@11:55PM** (UTC-09:00) Alaska*</sup>

## [One other note:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291745/sorting-of-top-users-by-tag/291749#comment947409_291745)

As [M.A.R.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291745/sorting-of-top-users-by-tag/291749#comment947409_291745) said as well, it requires less effort to respond less frequently. It may simply be that Shadow Wizard responded to more questions with relevance than simply being more *concise* and *helpful*.

Comment: my answer is in response to, "isn't that so?" Which is the last line of OP's post.

Comment: What's "Bg:"?  English is my first and pretty much only language and think I write English better than most English speakers but I do not recall ever seeing that written.  Is it a typo?

Comment: @PolyGeo No, it's an abbreviation for background. It should be double capitalized, but doing so will bring attention to it.

Comment: Why not just write "Background:"?  Or simply omit that heading?

Comment: @PolyGeo Writing out the full word brings attention to its length. Omitting it is probably better, but will possibly lead to readers skim reading my answer, and jumping over the background down to my section labelled "Yes."